# Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 0 seconds exceeded

Tags: php, command-line-interface, execution-time, litespeed

My script compares 2 source trees, creates a map of possible changed files, compares MD5 hashes and creates a diff-package.

After 28000-29000 files, PHP terminates the script with error:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 0 seconds exceeded in /root/_PACKER-TESTER/core/diff.class.php on line 67 (standard in_array() call)

I already tried to set `max_input_time` to high value (or zero) - nothing.

Setting `max_execution_time` to 99999999999999 do nothing .... the same error.

Comment: Your 999..999 time limit comes to about a 47 bit number, far above PHP's 32bit limit.

Comment: Are you running in SafeMode? ([docs for set_time_limit](http://us.php.net/set_time_limit) )...

Comment: Marc B - For this post I just press 9 many times not counting how many :) Ofkz in code I doesnt exceed 32 bits :)

Comment: ircmaxell - nope, I`m running from console at root permissions. Btw. safe mode is depraced

Comment: @kiler: I know it's deprecated, but safe mode has nothing to do with console or root permissions.  It's a php.ini setting...

Comment: I know :) I`m expirenced programmer and linux server administrator but in this situation I haven`t a clue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Problem solved, `php` build with `litespeed api (lsapi)` has extra `env` variable to determine **max** execute time - `LSAPI_MAX_PROCESS_TIME` (default is 300sec).

Comment: please mark your own answer as accepted to help others. and i think it would be cool if you added CLI environment to your tags/question.

Comment: it defaults to 300, but was it set to zero?

Comment: MAX_PROCESS_TIME is diffrent from php set time limit. Max process time has been added by litespeed tech to prevent evil script which loop for months doing nothing [set_time_limit() is cpu time, not real time]. LSAPI trigger internal php timeout mechanism, I reaported that to LiteSpeed tech. So, LSAPI_* env variables are highest priority than php values - it`s so cool on shared environments, user cant run script above global limits unless he obtain LiteSpeed Web Server config file or web panel access :)

Answer (score 31):

Try setting `max_input_time = -1` in `php.ini`, or using `set_time_limit(-1)`. That worked for me without rebuilding PHP.

[This article](https://web.archive.org/web/20120827105742/http://foolswisdom.com/php-fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-infinity-exceeded) explains it nicely.

Comment: Worked like charm, I had the same error and setting max_input_time = -1 did the work. Thanks

Comment: It not gotta work - LSAPI_* settings have higher priority than php.ini - admin can give user access to some options of php.ini without risk due to limiting implemented by LSAPI.

Comment: Just wanted to add that it appears that setting `0` or `-1` will have the same effect. Thanks for this, updating `max_input_time` was necessary (using `set_time_limit` in the code didn't change anything as appears to relate to `max_execution_time` which was already set to `0` for me). The error message seems to ouput whatever `max_execution_time` is set to even though its actually the `max_input_time` setting that is triggering the timeout. PHP 5.5.9 on ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

Try [set_time_limit()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.set-time-limit.php) and check in phpinfo() if you are able to set the time limit:

```
set_time_limit(60*60);phpinfo();exit;
```

Comment: set_time_limit() doesnt seems to help. I`m running script from console on dedicated server (I`m root).

Comment: This limit is not in effect in CLI.

Answer (score -1):

I've found the "max execution time of 0 seconds exceeded" can be caused by the code going into an infinite loop.

For example:

```
while (true) { ... }
```

causes this error for me.

If it's not an environment variable (as mentioned previously) I would examine what's on the line number reported by php with the error

Comment: Infinite loops are always a problem but some scripts run really long and have to run really long. 
So your answer is not appropriate here.