# PHP: Max execution time 0 exceeded

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, max-execution-timeout

I am using laravel 5.5.* and MySQL for the database. And when I am running a script I am receiving an error message saying that `Maximum execution time of 0 seconds exceeded`.

Anyone have any understanding as to what would be causing this error message?

> [2017-11-18 11:40:50] live.ERROR: Maximum execution time of 0 seconds exceeded {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException(code: 1): Maximum execution time of 0 seconds exceeded at /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php:826)
>
> [stacktrace]
>
> #0 {main}
>
> "}
>
> [2017-11-18 13:04:01] live.ERROR: Maximum execution time of 0 seconds exceeded {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException(code: 1): Maximum execution time of 0 seconds exceeded at /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:163)
>
> [stacktrace]
>
> #0 {main}
>
> "}

My settings for PHP have the `max_execution_time = 0` So it should never timeout. However it seems to be taking the 0 literally, and timing out straight away.

Is this a laravel setting ? Or is it something to do with the database?

---

UPDATE:

When I change the max_execution_time = 1 I get this response.

> [2017-11-18 13:25:23] live.ERROR: Maximum execution time of 1 second exceeded {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException(code: 1): Maximum execution time of 1 second exceeded at /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/MySqlGrammar.php:185)
>
> [stacktrace]
>
> #0 {main}
>
> "}

Note: It does timeout after 1 second with 1, however when I have it on 0. It doesnt seem to time out straight away. Im unable to know exactly how long, but it lasts longer than 20 seconds, and possible a couple minutes at least.

Comment: For reference; to ignore the value it can be set to `-1`, and not zero.

Comment: Also does [**this Q&A**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869611/fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-0-seconds-exceeded) help you?

Comment: oh I might actually try -1

Comment: Adding both `-1` to `max_execution_time` and `max_input_time` worked.

Comment: @KevinUpton can you mark the answer please?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting both `max_execution_time = 0` and `max_input_time = -1`. I had a similar issue where it was taking the 0 as literal. After I also max_input_time it worked.